# Getting values from a query that retrieves two entites in jasper reports

Tags: java, jpa, jasper-reports, ireport

i am using ireport 4.1.1 with hibernate jpa and I have a query that retrieves two entities:

```
select a,b from TableA a left join a.tableBList b
```

I am trying to get the value of a and b, in java, it returns an array of objects (Object[]) with two items, but when I try to do this on jasper reports it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : fieldName
```

I think that i only need to replace fieldName with the name of the object that will be returned but I don'w know it and I have tried to find it but I have had no success, anyone of you can help me please???

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure how hibrenate does it, but I would check if each row returned is an Object [], meaning if your query returns 5 rows, then you get back a list of 5 Object arrays. `Object[0]` would have `a` and `Object[1]` would have `b`. So maybe if you do `$F{fieldName}[0]` it would give your `a` and you could access the properties of that object.

Comment: @jschoen yes I have tried that and it should work, the problem is that I have to specify the field name but I can't get that name, for example, if my query returns an entity named 'person' this entity have a property named 'age', so if I want to access that property I declare a field named 'age' and I can get acces to that property with '$F{age}', but in the case that the query returns an array of two objects, I don't know what name give to the field, did I explain me??

Comment: Ahh, that is not the field. Your field is actually an object array. Say you name the object array `row` in your report then it would look something like `$F{row}[0].getAge()`. This may or may not work out the box as you probably need to cast the `$F{row}` to a `Person` class which means you will need to add the class to the class path of iReport to compile. But if you need to cast it should look like `((Person)$F{row}[0]).getAge()`. This is all off the top of my head, so your mileage might vary.

Comment: You could also process the results in java before passing the results to JasperReports. Taking the fields you want and creating a HashMap for each row. With the key being what you what to name the fields in the report. You would then use a JRMapCollectionDataSource as the datasource for the report.

Comment: yep, the problem is the name of the field, I don't know how to get the object array into a field, and processing before sendig to jasper reports is a good option but i'd have to change my report processing standard ... :(

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your data is not mapping with beans property, or you can that your data pattern is not according to the beans property. I was having the same problem in my java project. And I sorted out that your data should be in a proper 2D array form, then I took sample data from somewhere and did this

```
String[][] data =
{{ "N263Y", "T-11", " 39 ROSCOE TRNR RACER"},
{ "N4087X", "BA100-163", "BRADLEY AEROBAT"},
{ "N43JE", "HAYABUSA 1", "NAKAJIMA KI-43 IIIA"},
{ "N912S", "9973CC", "PA18-150"}};

        JTable m = new JTable(data,headers);
try {

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName);

            if(jasperReport != null )
               System.out.println("so far so good ");

            // Fill the report using an empty data source

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JRTableModelDataSource(m.getModel()) );//create());//con.connection);
            try{
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outFileName);
            System.out.printf("File exported sucessfully");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);

        } catch (JRException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

**Note:**

Your field name should start with small letters, moreover field names should be small as of the columns names u r providing within that data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: is it neccessary that I use an empty datasource? because in my report, I am doing 'nested' querys and an emptydatasource isn't functional to me, I need to do the querys inside the report